# window.history.pushState of back history

Tags: javascript

I change my browser url with the following javascript script:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "MyNewUrl");
```

After that, I want to go back to the previous Url.
I tried this:

```
window.history.back(); // This is working
```

But like with Pushstate behavior, I don't want to "load" the previous url. I just want to display it in the browser url.

It would be something like:

```
window.history.pushState.back(); // Not working (of course)
```

What do you suggest to achieve this?

EDIT

**The main goal:** 
When I click on a link it opens a modal then it pushes the url related to this particular modal in the browser.
When I close the modal, I want to push back the original url without loading it because it will go to the top of the page

Comment: What’s the purpose of this, what are you actually trying to achieve with this? Why push `MyNewUrl` to the history to begin with, if you want the previous URL to be shown immediately after?

Comment: I added the "goal" in my question

Comment: `window.history.back()` does not reload the page if the state was added with `pushState`.

Comment: Surely you just need to push another state when you close the modal - if you are adding the modal to you history, then you need to add the close of the modal to your history too if you want to return, otherwise there is no point in pushing anything to the history